# Python Question. Need an answer from Python Random In my script (beginner)

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I'm a beginner in Python, I need help. How to make the robot to choose 1, 2 or 3 and display it.

Here Is my Script.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x300')

sticks = 20

def computer():
    global sticks

    delete_sticks = random.randint(1, 3)
    sticks = delete_sticks

def player():
    global sticks

    delete_sticks = int(entry_sticks.get())

    if delete_sticks in [1,2,3]:
        sticks -= delete_sticks
        label_sticks.config(text="|"*sticks)
        status.config(text=sticks)
        if sticks == 1:
            status.config(text='YOU WON!', fg='Green')
        else:
            window.after(200, computer)
            Label_move.config(text='Computers turn, please wait.')
            


Label_move = Label(text='Type in a number from 1 to 3', font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
Label_move.pack()

emptyspace1 = Label()
emptyspace1.pack()

entry_sticks = Entry(font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
entry_sticks.pack()

emptyspace2 = Label()
emptyspace2.pack()

label_sticks = Label(text = sticks*'|', font = ('Arial', 30,'bold'))
label_sticks.pack()

emptyspace3 = Label()
emptyspace3.pack()

status = Label(text = '0', font=('Arial', 30, 'bold'))
status.pack()

button = Button(text = 'Take sticks', font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'), command = player)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

Also for ones who did not understand the script...

def computer():
global sticks

```
delete_sticks = random.randint(1, 3)
sticks = delete_sticks
```

this is the def for the computer to answer

Answer (score 0):

Use **random.choice()** so as to make the choice

```
import random
l=[1,2,3]
value=random.choice(l)
print(value)
```

You can even use random.randint(start,stop) which will choose any number between the limits,'both inclusive'

```
value=random.randint(1,3)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already used `random.randint(1, 3)` to generate computer choice, but need to update the remaining sticks.

Suggest to put the update of remaining sticks in a function which can be called after player or computer choice:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x300')

sticks = 20

def update_sticks(delete_sticks):
    global sticks
    sticks -= delete_sticks
    label_sticks.config(text="|"*sticks)
    status.config(text=sticks)
    return sticks == 1

def computer():
    # you can put some logic to make computer more intelligence
    delete_sticks = random.randint(1, min(3, sticks-1))
    computer_choice.config(text=f"computer last take: {delete_sticks}")
    if update_sticks(delete_sticks):
        status.config(text="Computer Won!", fg="red")
    else:
        Label_move.config(text="Type in a number from 1 to 3")

def player():
    try:
        delete_sticks = int(entry_sticks.get())
        if delete_sticks in (1,2,3) and delete_sticks < sticks:
            if update_sticks(delete_sticks):
                status.config(text="You Won!", fg="green")
            else:
                Label_move.config(text="Computer's turn, please wait ...")
                window.after(200, computer)
        else:
            # user input invalid number of sticks
            raise
    except:
        Label_move.config(text="Invalid input")


Label_move = Label(window, text='Type in a number from 1 to 3', font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
Label_move.pack(pady=5)

entry_sticks = Entry(window, font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
entry_sticks.pack(pady=5)

label_sticks = Label(window, text=sticks*'|', font=('Arial', 30,'bold'))
label_sticks.pack(pady=5)

status = Label(window, text=sticks, font=('Arial', 30, 'bold'))
status.pack(pady=5)

button = Button(window, text='Take sticks', font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'), command=player)
button.pack(pady=5)

# show computer's last choice
computer_choice = Label(window)
computer_choice.pack(pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```